# torchaudio.io.StreamReader doesn't throw error when seeking to time stamp more than the duration of audio file

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pytorch, torchaudio

I am trying to get the audio chunk of audio file between specific start time and end time

Consider a audio of duration 10 seconds. Now i need to get chunk from 4 sec to 7 sec

torchaudio.info doesn't give correct `num_frames` for io.BytesIO flac audio file. So there is no way to find the total number of frames in the given audio to check for out of bounds start offset
Ref: https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/2524

What I did to get the chunk of audio with start and end offsets.

```py
def read_audio(audio_file, start, end):
    audio_file.seek(0)
    reader = StreamReader(audio_file)
    sample_rate = int(reader.get_src_stream_info(reader.default_audio_stream).sample_rate)

    reader.seek(start * sample_rate)
    reader.add_basic_audio_stream(frames_per_chunk=(end - start) * sample_rate)

    return list(reader.stream())[0].pop()
```

This is working as intended for start time less than the duration of audio file. But when we give the start time more than the duration of audio file, It doesn't throw error or return empty tensor.
Is there any way to know the given offsets are out of bounds.

Comment: Hi @lokesh I am the developer who write all the torchaudio IO. Can you file an issue? https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/new/choose I am not sure if throwing an error is the right way, but we can discuss more there.